# IPython notebook: debugging by stopping the execution at specific point

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, ipdb

i want to interactively debug code that is deeply hidden in some class.

I know that it is possible open the ipdb using

```
from IPython.core.debugger import Pdb
Pdb().set_trace()
```

This work also in ipython (jupyter) notebook.

Another possibility that I find very convenient when I am working in the terminal is to open a shell at a specific point using

```
from IPython import embed
embed()
```

and then use ipython directly to interact with variables etc.
However, if I use this in notebook, I get a ipython shell embedded into the notebook, and this shell does not even work well (e.g., if I use `print`, the kernel blocks).

What I would find most convenient is to interrupt the kernel execution at some predefined point in the code and keep all current variables, so that I can use another cell for debugging and the possibility to, e.g., develop and test new code with the current variables.
Is there some way to achieve this?